# Web Deploy to IIS fails. Why?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, .net-core, webdeploy

I am trying to deploy a .net core c# app to an IIS running on Windows Server 2016. I created a publish profile.  I click on `Validate Connection` button and get the following error, that I need to install Web Deploy and that Web Management Service should be started:

[image]

I did install Web Deploy 3.6 and the Web Management Service is definitely running.

[image]

Here is my profile.  The `Site Name` is AppPool\WebSiteName.  `User name` is the same as I logged in on the server with.

What am I missing?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Figured out the problem.  The `Server` entry needs to have the protocol.  So `http://winserver` instead of just the name of the box.